# Convert object with list back to a class and find specific data from the object

Tags: c#

I would like to create a function allow to get data from any classes with provide a key value, but I am stack when converting object back to the class. The following is my code.

```
var ListABC = new List<ABC>();
GetData(ListABC, typeof(ABC), "A1");
```

Here is my Function :-

```
Public void GetData(object obj, Type objType, string find)
    {
        // Note! not able to using (List<ABC>)obj, because you never know what tyoe of object will be pass in.
        // How to get list data of "A1" after List ABC as a object? assume this function allow any classes.
    }
```

Here is my class :-

```
 public class ABC {
        protected int _A1;
        protected bool _B1;
        protected string _C1;

        public int A1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._A1;
            }
            set
            {
                this._A1 = value;
            }
        }
        public bool B1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._B1;
            }
            set
            {
                this._B1 = value;
            }
        }
        public string C1
        {
            get
            {
                return this._C1;
            }
            set
            {
                this._C1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: make `GetData` generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel said, make GetData generic:

```
public void GetData<T>(IList<T> obj, string find)
{

}
```

and then call it like so:

```
GetData(ListABC, "A1");
```

You can even enforce constraints on T, for example:

```
public void GetData<T>(IList<T> obj, string find)
    where T: IConvertible
{

}
```

---

If you don't want to implement an interface on the list item objects you will pass here, you could also pass a func:

```
public void GetData<T>(IList<T> obj, Func<T, string> idFunc, string find)
{
    var matchingItems = obj.Where(o => idFunc(o) == find);
}
```

and call it like so:

```
GetData(ListABC, i => i.A1, "A1");
```

---

Edit: Do you just want `ListABC.Select(i => i.A1)` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the list like ListABC.Select(i => i.A1), but in dynamic way, like any of object(ex. ListABC or others object class) and key(ex. A1, B1, C1) and return as a list or array.

Comment: @Howard Where do your list objects come from? Do you know they have these keys at compile time? If not, how do you work out that they have these keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you want minimum change in your code. you can do it like below.

Although, making method generic is good idea, but as you are already passing type of `ABC` to the method, you are not required to make method generic.

*here type you have passed is suggesting which type of data list is holding*

**Assumptions:** you method's return type is void (so assuming you don't want anything to be returned. and also you are passing only one string `find` as a property to get so at a time you want data of only specified property.

if your requirements are simpler and scope of data is limited in your method only, you can always choose simpler way (which is easily understandable and readable)

try something like below,

```
public void GetData(object obj, Type objType, string find)
{
    //as you are passing type of list here, you can use it.
    if(objType == typeof(ABC))
    {
        List<ABC> list = (List<ABC>)obj;

        //now use it.

        //here we are getting the property with name as per find (name we passed in method)
        PropertyInfo prop = objType.GetProperty(find);
        //if there is no property with specified name, PropertyInfo object (prop) will be null
        if (prop != null)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
                foreach (ABC abcObj in list)
                {
                    object a1Data = prop.GetValue(abcObj);
                    int data = (int)a1Data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: drawback of this approach is, you need to handle cases of different Types in this method. So if your method may accept big variety of type, you may not want to go with this idea.